# SSL Certificate installation apache 2 not working

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, debian

I'm currently installing a Comodo certificate from Cheapssls.com. Im getting the following error:

> SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Im 100% sure the privatekey and the CSR are from the same generation

Im using the follinwg syntax:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache/conf/x-x-nl-new.key
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache/conf/x_x_nl.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/apache/conf/x_x_nl.ca-bundle
```

which is correct im my opinion.

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are your key on PEM format ?

It's needed by apache : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCertificateKeyFile

PEM is a Base64 encoded certificate, enclosed between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----".

You can check it with a simple file editor

**Edit1:**

You can also check that the modulus are the OK for that make a diff between Cert modulus and KEY modulus with this command.

```
# Change KEY and CERT by your file name
diff <(openssl rsa -in KEY -modulus -noout) <(openssl x509 -in CERT -modulus -noout)
```

You shouldn't have any out put, If you have some, the key and the certificate don't match.

Comment: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIB
........
nyUftgj26gSQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Thats my certificate, so yeh i think its base64 encoded...

Comment: I also used the comodo: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3&nav=0,1,33 generation method and installation method: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203

Comment: root@******:/usr/local/apache/conf# diff <(openssl rsa -in *****-*****-nl.key -modulus -noout) <(openssl x509 -in *****_****_nl.crt -modulus -noout)
root@******:/usr/local/apache/conf#
No output...so weird, looks like apache doesn't want to read it..?

Comment: Apache open it because you have an error :) I should do some more test before to propose you some thing else. Maybe could you try with home made (self signed) cert just for testing purpose ?

Comment: The problem is that the Apache is currently running another VHost with an SSL certificate from Thawte. That is working flawlessly so there ain't a problem with mod ssl or anything. If i apply the Thawte certificate (which is false because of a different domain) to that vhost its working perfect

Comment: "*[...] -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- Thats my certificate*": no, that's your private key.